Chat Playground, View Code Issue With GPT4o and Multiple attachments
Using Azure OpenAI Chat Playground and I went to get the code for my conversation, but the user messages are missing. I uploaded two jpgs and asked for a transcription and a translation, and received the correct output, but I wanted to review the code it generated so that I could get an example of how the attachments are sent.
Why are the user messages missing, and is this a bug, or is there something I can do to see the SDK implementation of the messages that were sent?
// Note: The Azure OpenAI client library for .NET is in preview.
// Install the .NET library via NuGet: dotnet add package Azure.AI.OpenAI --prerelease
using Azure;
using Azure.AI.OpenAI;

OpenAIClient client = new OpenAIClient(
  new Uri("https://[our endpoint].openai.azure.com/"),
  new AzureKeyCredential(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY")));

  Response<ChatCompletions> responseWithoutStream = await client.GetChatCompletionsAsync(
  "GPT4o",
  new ChatCompletionsOptions()
  {
    Messages =
    {
      new ChatMessage(ChatRole.System, @"You are an AI assistant that helps people find information."),
      new ChatMessage(ChatRole.Assistant, @"json
{
  \"TranscribedText\": \"[Transcribed text was all here, and very good.]",
  
  \"TranslatedText\": \"[Translation was here, and was very good as well.]"
}

/* I asked for another translation, just to see if there was a glitch generating the user messages with just one user message but it isn't included either. */
"),      new ChatMessage(ChatRole.Assistant, @"json
{
  \"TranscribedText\": \"[Trascribed text was given here.]",
  
  \"TranslatedText\": \"[New translation was given here.]\"
}
"),
    },
    Temperature = (float)0.7,
    MaxTokens = 800,
    NucleusSamplingFactor = (float)0.95,
    FrequencyPenalty = 0,
    PresencePenalty = 0,
  });


ChatCompletions response = responseWithoutStream.Value;

I am using a deployment of GPT4o.
As an alternative, I opened up the browser developer tools to see what the site was sending, and see that the images are sent as dataurls (I see that in the call), but I was hoping for the C# code using the Azure OpenAI SDK to see how it is done through that route.

Can you please specify, what exactly your question is?

@91378246 Apologies, I thought it was clear with " the user messages are missing" but I will make it explicit.

I cannot answer the first part of the question as to why the Azure OpenAI interface is not showing the UserMessages when there are attachments, but I did confirm when I do not use the GPT4o deployment, and use just a GPT4 deployment, I do see the sent user messages:
// Note: The Azure OpenAI client library for .NET is in preview.
// Install the .NET library via NuGet: dotnet add package Azure.AI.OpenAI --prerelease
using Azure;
using Azure.AI.OpenAI;

OpenAIClient client = new OpenAIClient(
  new Uri("https://[our endpoint].openai.azure.com/"),
  new     AzureKeyCredential(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_OPENAI_API_KEY"))    );

  Response<ChatCompletions> responseWithoutStream = await client.GetChatCompletionsAsync(
  "Assistants_Playground_Test",
  new ChatCompletionsOptions()
  {
    Messages =
    {
      new ChatMessage(ChatRole.System, @"You are an AI assistant that helps people find information."),
      **new ChatMessage(ChatRole.User, @"Please provide a translation for \"Hola\" from Spanish to English"),**      new ChatMessage(ChatRole.Assistant, @"\"Hola\" translates from Spanish to English as \"Hello\"."),
},
Temperature = (float)0.7,
MaxTokens = 800,
NucleusSamplingFactor = (float)0.95,
FrequencyPenalty = 0,
PresencePenalty = 0,
});


ChatCompletions response = responseWithoutStream.Value;

From the following MS Learn document, I was able to answer the overall question, of how do you send images with your User ChatMessage calls:

If you want to use a local image, you can use the following Python
code to convert it to base64 so it can be passed to the API

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/how-to/gpt-with-vision?tabs=rest%2Csystem-assigned%2Cresource
Then I found this SO answer showing how to create a dataurl in C#:

return "<img src="data:image/"
+ Path.GetExtension(imgFile).Replace(".","")
+ ";base64,"
+ Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(imgFile)) + "" />";

how to convert Image to Data URI for Html with C#?
The DataUrl ended up being too long though, and as noted here:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/pull/43830
I was able to use the call:

ChatMessageImageContentItem is augmented with two new constructors: one accepts a BinaryData for the image and a matching string for the image format's MIME type (like image/png);

The C# code that ended up working for me was:
// Note: The Azure OpenAI client library for .NET is in preview.
// Install the .NET library via NuGet: dotnet add package Azure.AI.OpenAI --prerelease
using Azure;
using Azure.AI.OpenAI;
using Azure.Core;

BinaryData binaryData = BinaryData.FromBytes(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));
var imageContent = new ChatMessageImageContentItem(binaryData, "image/jpg");

OpenAIClient client = new OpenAIClient(
  new Uri("https://[my endpoint].openai.azure.com/"),
  new AzureKeyCredential("[my key]"));

Response<ChatCompletions> responseWithoutStream = await client.GetChatCompletionsAsync(
new ChatCompletionsOptions()
{
    Messages =
  {
      new ChatRequestSystemMessage(@"You are an AI assistant that helps people find information."),
      new ChatRequestUserMessage(new ChatMessageContentItem[]{ imageContent,new ChatMessageTextContentItem("Please transcribe and then translate the transcription from English to Spanish.") })},
    Temperature = (float)0.7,
    MaxTokens = 800,
    DeploymentName = "GPT4o",
    NucleusSamplingFactor = (float)0.95,
    FrequencyPenalty = 0,
    PresencePenalty = 0,
    });


    ChatCompletions response = responseWithoutStream.Value;
    Console.WriteLine(response.Choices[0].Message.Content);


You are not passing the user messages correctly in the options.
        string prompt = "My User Prompt";
        var chatCompletionsOptions = new ChatCompletionsOptions()
        {
            DeploymentName = "your chat model",
            Messages =
            {
                new ChatRequestSystemMessage("Respond to the user truthfully."),
                new ChatRequestUserMessage(prompt)
            }
        };

The above will prompt the API for the system message, then the user message.

I appreciate the try, but the question is about the Azure OpenAI User Interface not producing the correct code. The call that I am not seeing in the code that is generated from the Azure OpenAI interface is the message where I attach the image and prompt for the transcription and translation. Perhaps this is not a good SO question, or perhaps I need to split out the "why didn't the UI give me the complete code?" and the "what is the complete code?" questions.

Totally understand. The user interface MAY not be producing the correct code. This answer gives you the 'complete' code, as this will function with the ability to ask the prompt questions.
